# How do I make my player still use jump animation while in air and moving

Tags: python, pygame

So I have two different type's of jump animation "jump1" is when the player starts jumping while "jump2" if for the player falling after it jumps, I was wondering how would you make it so that when the player jumps and starts moving, it will still be doing it's jump animation. It's not working for me because I have an move right and left animation so evetime I jump and try to move it will go to the other animation's.

https://gyazo.com/9fa313e7e063ab3f08e224ef5bba2db5

What I wrote for my jump animation

```
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    px, py = playerman.x, playerman.y

    for Platform in platforms:    
        if playerman.fall > 0 and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            playerman.direction = "jump2"
        else:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.direction = "jump1"
```

My full code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Noobs First Game")


move = pygame.image.load("WASD.png")


# Playerman
class Player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.idle =[pygame.image.load("player_idel_1.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_2.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_3.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_4.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_5.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_6.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_7.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_8.png")
                            ]

        self.idlel = [pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left1.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left2.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left3.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left4.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left5.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left6.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left7.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left8.png")
                         ]
        self.right = [pygame.image.load("Player_walk_right1.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_walk_right2.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_walk_right3.png")]
        
        self.left = [pygame.image.load("Player_walk_left1.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_walk_left2.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_walk_left3.png")]

        self.jump1 = [pygame.image.load("Player_jump1.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_jump2.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_jump3.png")]
        
        self.jump2 = [
                     pygame.image.load("Player_jump5.png")]

        self.fall = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.idle = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2,image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.idle]
        self.idlel = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2,image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.idlel]
        self.right = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2,image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.right]
        self.left = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2, image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.left]
        self.jump1 = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2,image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.jump1]
        self.jump2 = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2,image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.jump2]
        self.fps = 10
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.anim_index = 0
        self.direction = "idle"
        self.direction = "right"
        self.direction = "left"
        self.dierection = "idleleft"
        self.dierection = "jump1"
        self.dierection = "jump2"
        self.next_frame_time = 0
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
        pygame.draw.rect(self.color,self.rect)
    
    def draw(self):
        if self.direction == "idle":
            image_list = self.idle
        if self.direction == "right":
            image_list = self.right
        if self.direction == "left":
            image_list = self.left
        if self.direction == "idlel":
            image_list = self.idlel
        if self.direction == "jump1":
            image_list = self.jump1
        if self.direction == "jump2":
            image_list = self.jump2
    

         

        # Is it time to show the next animation frame?
        time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if ( time_now > self.next_frame_time ):
            # set the time for the next animation-frame
            inter_frame_delay = 1000 // self.fps   
            self.next_frame_time = time_now + inter_frame_delay  # in the future
            # move the current image to the next (with wrap-around)
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index >= len( image_list ):
                self.anim_index = 0
                    
        if self.anim_index >= len(image_list):
            self.anim_index = 0
        player_image = image_list[self.anim_index]

        pygame.draw.rect( window, self.color, self.get_rect(), 2 )
        player_image = image_list[self.anim_index]

        player_rect = player_image.get_rect(center = self.get_rect().center)
        player_rect.centerx += 3
        player_rect.centery -= 13
        window.blit(player_image, player_rect)
        


class Platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y
        self. width = width
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 4
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.get_rect())


class Rule:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y
        self. width = width
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 4
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


# Colors for hitbox
white = (255,255,255)
green = (0,255,0)

# Drawing Player
playerman = Player(350,445,40,40,white)

#Drawing Platforms
platform1 = Platform(300,-9.1,40,500,green)
platform2 = Platform(330,451,2000,40,green)
platform3 = Platform(2300,-9.1,40,500,green)

# Drawing Rule
rule1 = Rule(340,-9.1,220,500,green)
rule2 = Rule(20000,-9,1,5,green)

# List
platforms = [platform1,platform2,platform3]

rules = [rule1,rule2]


# draws map
platformGroup = pygame.sprite.Group
Level = [
"                                         1   1",
"                                         1    ",
"                         1  1        111 1    ",
"                         1  1         1  1    ",
"                         11 1      1  1 11    ",
"                         1  1         1  1    ",
"                         1  1    1    11 1    ",
"           1   1   111   1 11         1  1    ",
"           1   1  11111        1      1          ",]

for iy,row in enumerate(Level):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "1":
            new_platforms = Platform(ix*50,iy*50.2,50,50,(255,255,255))
            platforms.append(new_platforms)
    
            

# Windows color
def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))

    # Drawing the player and other stuff to the screen
    playerman.draw()

    for Platform in platforms:
        Platform.draw()
    for Rule in rules:
        Rule.draw()

x = 10
y = 10
x_change = 0
y_change = 0
old_x = x
old_y = y
fps = (30)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            
    


    if playerman.y < 250:
        playerman.y += 1
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.y += playerman.speed

    if playerman.y > 410:
        playerman.y -= playerman.fall
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.y -= playerman.fall

    
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            x_change = -7
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            x_change = 7

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
            x_change = 0

        x += x_change
        if x > 500 - playerman.width or x < 0:
            x = old_x
           
        # lets player move
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    px, py = playerman.x, playerman.y

    for Platform in platforms:    
        if playerman.fall > 0 and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            playerman.direction = "jump2"
        else:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.direction = "jump1"
                

    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x -= playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x -= playerman.speed

        playerman.direction = "right"
        
       
    elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x += playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x += playerman.speed
        playerman.direction = "left"

    
    else:
        if playerman.direction == "left":
            playerman.direction = "idlel"
        else:
            if playerman.direction == "right":
                
                playerman.direction = "idle"

    platform_rect_list = [p.rect for p in platforms]
    player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
    player_rect.topleft = (px, py)

    playerman.y = py
    if player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list) < 0:
        playerman.x = px

    move_right = keys[pygame.K_d]
    move_left = keys[pygame.K_a]
    if move_right: 
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x -= playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x -= playerman.speed     # <---
    if move_left:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x += playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x += playerman.speed     # <---

    platform_rect_list = [p.get_rect() for p in platforms] # get_rect()
    player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
    player_rect.topleft = (px, py)

    playerman.y = py
    cI = player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list)
    if cI >= 0:
        # undo movement of platforms dependent on the direction and intersection distance
        dx = 0
        if move_right: 
            dx = platform_rect_list[cI].left - player_rect.right
        if move_left:
            dx = platform_rect_list[cI].right - player_rect.left
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x -= dx
            Platform.get_rect() # update rectangle
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x -= dx             # <---

##############                
  
    # About isJump
    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        playerman.isJump = False

        # this part lets you jump on platform only the top 
        collide = False
        for Platform in platforms:
            if playerman.get_rect().colliderect(Platform.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.y = Platform.rect.top - playerman.height
                if playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.right
                       
            # colliding with floor      
            if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.Jumpcount = 10
                playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height

        # Jumping
        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
                py -= playerman.speed
            playerman.fall = 0
            

    # Jump Count

    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount >= 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10

    redrawwindow()
    if playerman.rect.colliderect(rule1.rect):
        window.blit(move,(-40,-100))
    
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`playerman.direction` just state the kind of animation. The movement is determined by `move_right`, `move_left` and `playerman.isJump`.
Don't change `playerman.direction` if `playerman.isJump` is set:

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x -= playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x -= playerman.speed
        if not playerman.isJump:
            playerman.direction = "right"
        
    elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x += playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x += playerman.speed
        if not playerman.isJump:
            playerman.direction = "left"

    elif playerman.isJump:
        if playerman.fall > 0:
            playerman.direction = "jump2"
        else:
            playerman.direction = "jump1" 
    
    else:
        playerman.direction = "idle"
```

Comment: It's only playing one of my animation "jump1"

Comment: @Windowman This is another bug. I've extended the code in the answer.